# webpack historyApiFallback not working?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a single-page-app which uses the history API. So I set `historyApiFallback:true` in my config file, but I still get `404` for any unknown file

Command-line: `webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --hot --inline --progress --devtool eval`

Config file:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  entry: {
    main: [
      './src/main'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/, query: { presets: ['es2015-loose', 'stage-1'], plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'] } },
      { test: /\.css?$/, loader: 'style!css' },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html' },
      { test: /\.(png|gif|jpg)$/, loader: 'url?limit=8192' },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff2' },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file' }
    ]
  }
};
```

It builds just fine, but if I try to get a file that doesn't exist, I just get a `404` rather than my `index.html`:

```
$ curl -i localhost:3000/asbasas
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 20
Date: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 18:27:33 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Cannot GET /asbasas
```

Webpack version:

```
$ webpack-dev-server --help
webpack-dev-server 1.14.1
```

So... what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I do get a message on startup that

```
404s will fallback to /index.html
```

But still...

Answer (score 1):

OK, my error. When I did this on my own, I set it up so if the file had an extension, it wouldn't fall back to `/index.html`, but I ran my test with an extension. My own mistake.

And the whole time I was thinking, "how can I add that functionality?"

Answer (score 0):

```
devServer: {
contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
publicPath: "/",
historyApiFallback: true,
compress: true,
port: 3000,
hot: true,
open: "chrome"}
```

it configuration work in path "/posts" but not in "/posts/:slug", maybe wrong?